# Alert box is not displayed on vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

Hi I have a simple todo web app that I have deployed on vercel.

Here I have a Update Task where I enter the task id and name and summary and after update it should give me a alert saying that the task updated.

It works fine on my local host but on vercel there is not alert box, the task update is working fine but I am not able to figure out why it doesn't show the box.

Here is the url: https://to-do-app-git-main-ashuk2000.vercel.app/

Here is the repo: https://github.com/ashuk2000/ToDo-App

The lines where ṭhe put request is sent and handled https://github.com/ashuk2000/ToDo-App/blob/f13b618f111e7ad5cbebf1f9066f0c6595e9a8a5/frontend/validation.js#L55

Can anybody please help me figure out why no alert is displayed

it prints on console for a split second and then the message is gone

Comment: I am suspecting this might be the problem
https://github.com/ashuk2000/ToDo-App/blob/f13b618f111e7ad5cbebf1f9066f0c6595e9a8a5/vercel.json